# Reason for converting VHDX files into qcow2 files in using UTM(virtual windows11 on apple silicon)

Tags: utm

I'm just wondering that reasons for converting VHDX files into qcow2 files in using UTM program.

I want to use windows11 on m1 mac, and I saw a post by others.

But they said "Convert VHDX file into qcow2 file.", I wonder that reasons for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less for performance.`VHDX` files are converted into `qcow2` as it better integrates with the `qemu` architecture which is used for virtualisation on Apple Silicon Macs (M1+).

This conversion is done automatically by UTM when creating the virtual machine manually converting is no longer necessary.